# Why I cannot get indexed on Google but it works well on Bing (Vercel/NextJS)?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, bing-webmaster-tools, technical-seo

I have recently launched a new website using Vercel and NextJS and am trying to get it indexed on Google using Google Search console. The Bing console worked like a charm however I cannot get it indexed on Google.

When I hit "request indexing" it returns "Indexing request rejected"
[image]

When I hit "View live test"
[image]

Same for the sitemap, google doesn't want to fetch it
[image]

My robot.txt

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

My HTTP headers

```
% curl -I http://estimationfrancaise.fr/ 
HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
Date: Tue, 21 Sep 2021 07:02:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://estimationfrancaise.fr/
Refresh: 0;url=https://estimationfrancaise.fr/
server: Vercel
x-vercel-id: cdg1::f22rp-1632207769716-975691dae8e5
```

My HTTPS headers

```
% curl -I https://estimationfrancaise.fr/ 
HTTP/2 200 
date: Tue, 21 Sep 2021 08:14:53 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
x-matched-path: /fr
cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-length: 129959
content-disposition: inline
access-control-allow-origin: *
etag: W/"09bfd05866e2fae1301168b990c48e0d8125b90a75dbba66efca7163f86ec8d4"
accept-ranges: bytes
x-vercel-cache: HIT
age: 4721
server: Vercel
x-vercel-id: cdg1::qzchq-1632212093135-8af9564c54f7
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
```

Comment: "Couldn't fetch" is often a temporary problem with the network connectivity between your site and Google.   We have a bunch of questions related to it: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=google%20couldn%27t%20fetch

Comment: Thanks! Not sure to understand how come google could not fetch my website if websites like https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html can?

Comment: Google itself has network problems on their end from time to time.  Not sure that is the case here, but it is a possibility.